# Replacing a for loop with an iterator in java?

Tags: java

How would I write an iterator for this code?  I want to remove multiple entries based on input.

```
public void cancelRegistration(String someName)
{
    for (Name n: ArrayList)
    {
        if(n.Name.equals(someName))
        {
            ArrayList.remove(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/ArrayListiterator.htm

Comment: You have a class called `Name` with an `String` instance variable called `Name`? You should really learn java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Iterator.remove()`.

Assuming you have a class called `Name` with a `String` field called `Name` and assuming the class `cancelRegistration` is in has a field called `ArrayList` of type `List<Name>`:

```
public void cancelRegistration(String someName) {
    for (Iterator<Name> iterator = ArrayList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
        if (iterator.next().Name.equals(someName))
            iterator.remove();
}
```